# How to create Primefaces radioButtons from List?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, radio-button

I want to create a set of Radiobuttons from a List of Objects `#{item.items3}` and store the selected object into `#{cartBean.selectedChoice}`. Now I don't really get the difference between the values needed for `<f:selectItems>` and `<ui:repeat>`. How does my code look. Any obvious mistakes so far?

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="myRadio" value="#{cartBean.selectedChoice}" layout="custom">
    <f:selectItems value="#{item.items3}"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>

<h:panelGrid columns="1">
    <ui:repeat var="choice" value="#{item.items3}" varStatus="choiceIndex">
        <p:radioButton id="choiceRadio" for=":iterateCategories:iterateItems:lightForm:myRadio" itemIndex="#{choiceIndex.index}" />#{choice.name}
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGrid>
```

At the moment I am getting the following Error:

> 20:58:52,397 INFO 
>   [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit]
>   (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been
>   enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
>   sourceId=iterateCategories:0:iterateItems:2:lightForm:myRadio[severity=(ERROR
>   2), summary=(Conversion Error setting value
>   'huhu.model.generated.Item@3ae5e1dc' for 'null Converter'.),
>   detail=(Conversion Error setting value
>   'huhu.model.generated.Item@3ae5e1dc' for 'null Converter'.)]

I don't understand, where there could be a conversion problem as only objects of the same class are dealt with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF generates HTML. HTML is basically one large string. Non-string typed Java objects needs therefore to be converted to string. If a type is encountered for which either no builtin converter (`Number`, `Boolean` and `Enum`) nor a custom converter (a class implementing `Converter`) is found, then the object's default `toString()` implementation will be used to print the complex Java object into the HTML output. If your object doesn't have this method overridden, then it will be the `Object#toString()`'s default implementation which is described in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> The toString method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@`, and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

In your particular case, the generated HTML radio button element becomes the following:

```
<input type="radio" ... value="huhu.model.generated.Item@3ae5e1dc" />
```

*(rightclick the page in browser and choose View Source to see it yourself)*

Now, when this form is submitted, the very input value `huhu.model.generated.Item@3ae5e1dc` which is collected by `request.getParameter()` (which returns `String`!) has to be converted back to a concrete instance of your custom type `Item`. However, as there's apparently no converter been registered for the custom type (error message already hints this: "null converter"), JSF is unable to convert it back to `Item` and will throw this converter exception.

You should really be providing a custom converter which properly converts between `Item` and its unique `String` representation. More than often a technical ID (such as the autogenerated PK from the database) is been used as unique `String` representation. The converter would then look like as follows:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Item.class)
public class ItemConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public void getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) throws ConverterException {
        // Write code to convert Item to its unique String representation. E.g.
        return String.valueOf(((Item) modelValue).getId());
    }

    @Override 
    public void getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object submittedValue) throws ConverterException {
        // Write code to convert unique String representation of Item to concrete Item. E.g.
        return someItemService.find(Long.valueOf(submittedValue));
    }
    
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`SelectItemsConverter`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/converter/SelectItemsConverter.html) of the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) so that the converter will instead use the `<f:selectItem(s)>` as conversion basis. This way you don't need to create a custom converter for every custom Java type which you'd like to use in `<f:selectItem(s)>`. See also [the `SelectItemsConverter` showcase page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter):

```
<p:selectOneRadio ... converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer providing the info needed to setup converters on your own. As I am not sure, what other Java type I might have to cast I chose the omnifaces alternative to handle the conversion issues.

Comment: What I still don't get is the difference between value of `<f:selectItems>` and `<ui:repeat>`. Is `<ui:repeat>` even neccessary?

Comment: The `<ui:repeat>` is necessary because you used `layout="custom"` (with which you're basically specifying that you'd like to present and style every individual item *yourself* instead of relying on the default presentation). If you remove `layout="custom"`, then it's indeed not necessary.

Comment: That definitely makes sense. But where do I get the value for the `itemIndex`-attribute for `<p:radioButton>` from?