# jsf primefaces, show itemLabel not itemvalue on update

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have 2 items:
radiobuttons
outputtext

What I'm trying to do is: When the user checks a radiobutton -> get the itemLabel of the checked radiobutton in my outputtext. (not itemValue)

I have following code which shows the itemValue in the output text:

```
<h:form>
<p:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection" id="test" name="testy" value="#{myBean.testValue}">
<p:ajax update="testOutput"/>
<p:selectItems value="#{myBean.getAllTestItems()}" var="selecter" itemLabel="#{selecter.label}" itemValue="#{selecter.val}"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>

<h:outputText id="testOutput" value="#{myBean.testValue}"/>
</h:form>
```

When i select one of the radiobuttons, I get the itemValue in the outputText. However I would like to get the itemLabel of the selected item in the outputText.

How do I get the label instead of the value of the radiobutton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways.

1. Get it based on the collection behind `#{myBean.getAllTestItems()}` which already contains the items with both the label and the value. Find the item matching the selected value in there and then get the label.
2. Submit `#{selecter}` instead of `#{selecter.val}` as radio button item value. This way you can display the label by `#{myBean.testValue.label}`. You only need to provide a [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) to convert between `String` (in HTML and HTTP request parameter) and `Selecter` (in Java model).

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)
- [How to create Primefaces radioButtons from List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129028/how-to-create-primefaces-radiobuttons-from-list/13129706#13129706) (for the case you'd like to use `Selecter` as value)